# How to preselect checkboxes with closure templates?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-templates

In a closure template I receive 2 lists (divisions, offices) and offices can be associated with some divisions ( divisions.officeLocations[] ).

How can I preselect checkboxes (offices from divisions divisions.officeLocations[]) from all the offices (full list) received in the template using the closure-templates functions without doing something like this that looks very confusing and completely wrong ?

```
{foreach $division in $divisions}
    {foreach $office in $offices}
        {foreach $officeInDivision in $division.officeLocations}
            [...]
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Do I need to receives all the offices available in each division object (in divisions) with a parameter checked at true/false ? Somehting like that which looks wrong too ?

```
{foreach $division in $divisions}
    {foreach $office in $division.officesLocations}
        {if $office.checked}
            [...]
        {else}
            [...]
        {/if}
    {/foreach}                  
{/foreach}
```

thanks a lot !

Comment: This is confusing. please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Is this still unanswered? Please provide a markup example of what you want the template to output.